# I want to make two button one that maximise and the other one that minimise the size of the page of my browser

Tags: php, button, resize, max, min

I created a form in a table, but i need to adjust the size with Ctrl - and Ctrl +... But i want to make two button one that can minimize the page and another button that could maximize the page of my browser just by clicking on them. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean resizing the browser window?

Comment: No resize the browser page inside the browser... I want to resize the page inside the browser

Comment: Consider using the ``KeyboardEvent`` built-in API in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent